# How to start Android OS without GUI, like linux without desktop?

Tags: android, linux

I want let my android phone as a mini server.

At first, I want to install a `linux server OS` on the phone, but there is no real tutorial to teach how to install a linux OS on a phone (most of them just tell u to install a vm app or a different phone OS).

Later, I find `android OS` is based on Linux kerner. I know a `Linux OS` will run the `init` program after the kernel boot is complete, so, did andriod have a "`init 3`" to only start console without GUI (desktop)?

Comment: Android as a product is tied to its hardware, see: [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/3573) and [Why does Android differ so much from Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/149369/3573) So while you can get root and Linux-like environments, you are still running the Android kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that because while android uses the linux kernel, it is not the same as the one on desktop. It is a modified version with many differences. If you want to access a terminal on your phone you can download a app called "Termux".